# Filter data in autocomplete list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, filtering

I want to send value "merk" to "modelName", and the result if I choose "ÄUDI" for example, in my autocomplete dropdownlist will only show Audi's model car.

here is my aspx.cs

```
private void Get_data (string merkName)
{
    List<string> modelNames = new List<string>();

    string cs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cs);
    {
        OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand("Package_AUTOCOMPLETE.get_data", conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_STRING", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 80)).Value = searchTxt;
        comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_MERK", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 80)).Value = merkName;
        comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_CURSOR", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_ERROR_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        conn.Open();
        OracleDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            modelNames.Add(rdr["MODEL_DESC"].ToString());
        }
    }
}

protected void ddlMerk_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
    //string model = "";
    string merk = "";
    merk = ddlMerk.SelectedItem.ToString();        

    Get_data(merk);
}
```

here is my jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('#<%=searchTxt.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "default2.asmx/getModelName",
                data: "{ 'modelName': '" + request.term + "' }",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d.slice(0, 10));
                    response(data.d);
                },
                //error: function (result) {
                //    alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                //    console.log("err res->>",result);
                //}
            });
        },
    minLength: 3
    });
});
```

please kindly help to give a solution, thank you :)

here is my Json view

[
{
"MERK_ID": "1",
"MERK_NAME": "AUDI",
"TYPE_NAME": "A3",
"MODEL_NAME": "1.2 TFSI",
"MODEL_DESC": "AUDI-A3-1.2 TFSI"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "1",
"MERK_NAME": "AUDI",
"TYPE_NAME": "A3",
"MODEL_NAME": "NEW 2.0 FSI SPORTBACK TRIPTRONIC",
"MODEL_DESC": "AUDI-A3-NEW 2.0 FSI SPORTBACK TRIPTRONIC"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "1",
"MERK_NAME": "AUDI",
"TYPE_NAME": "A3",
"MODEL_NAME": "S3 LIMOUSINE 2.0 TFSI QUATTRO",
"MODEL_DESC": "AUDI-A3-S3 LIMOUSINE 2.0 TFSI QUATTRO"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "2",
"MERK_NAME": "BAJAJ",
"TYPE_NAME": "AVENGER",
"MODEL_NAME": "CRUISE 220",
"MODEL_DESC": "BAJAJ-AVENGER-CRUISE 220"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "2",
"MERK_NAME": "BAJAJ",
"TYPE_NAME": "AVENGER",
"MODEL_NAME": "STREET 160",
"MODEL_DESC": "BAJAJ-AVENGER-STREET 160"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "2",
"MERK_NAME": "BAJAJ",
"TYPE_NAME": "CT",
"MODEL_NAME": "100",
"MODEL_DESC": "BAJAJ-CT-100"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "3",
"MERK_NAME": "BENELLI",
"TYPE_NAME": "502C",
"MODEL_NAME": "500 CC",
"MODEL_DESC": "BENELLI-502C-500 CC"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "3",
"MERK_NAME": "BENELLI",
"TYPE_NAME": "CAFERACER",
"MODEL_NAME": "1130 CC",
"MODEL_DESC": "BENELLI-CAFERACER-1130 CC"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "3",
"MERK_NAME": "BENELLI",
"TYPE_NAME": "LEONCINO",
"MODEL_NAME": "250",
"MODEL_DESC": "BENELLI-LEONCINO-250"
},

Comment: difficult to help you without your json output, because i suppose you want to filter the output

Comment: I already edited the question with list of string

Comment: its not what i want, you have data in output, in format json which have property merk and so on

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding I was just know how to convert table to Json, I already edit the question with json view. please your help. if you need anything else to clear the solution, just ask me.

Comment: what is the code of response, and your json is data or data.d?

Comment: Here is the response code "net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)",  and for the data I'm not understand the different, cause when I use data and data.d it show the same result

Comment: so you have nothing in the autocomplete with this code?

Comment: ah, the autocomplete will show the model_desc, the string of model_desc for the autocomplete is already shown before I insert the dropdownlist form Merk, and I think I the jquery that I saw from tutorial is only get one inputted, but i need to input two input

Comment: dont forget to validate and upvote the answer if your problem is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have adapted a sample without ajax, following your json:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    
    //to put in section success of your ajax ------------------
    //regex to select data which starts with the input (nocase)
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + request.term,"i");
    //filter data following the input
    var ndata = data.filter((d) => regex.test(d.MERK_NAME));
     response($.map(ndata, function(item) {
     return {
     label: item.MODEL_DESC,
        }

   }));
      
    },
    minLength: 3,
  });



});

var data = [{
    "MERK_ID": "1",
    "MERK_NAME": "AUDI",
    "TYPE_NAME": "A3",
    "MODEL_NAME": "1.2 TFSI",
    "MODEL_DESC": "AUDI-A3-1.2 TFSI"
  },
  {
    "MERK_ID": "1",
    "MERK_NAME": "AUDI",
    "TYPE_NAME": "A3",
    "MODEL_NAME": "NEW 2.0 FSI SPORTBACK TRIPTRONIC",
    "MODEL_DESC": "AUDI-A3-NEW 2.0 FSI SPORTBACK TRIPTRONIC"
  },
  {
    "MERK_ID": "1",
    "MERK_NAME": "AUDI",
    "TYPE_NAME": "A3",
    "MODEL_NAME": "S3 LIMOUSINE 2.0 TFSI QUATTRO",
    "MODEL_DESC": "AUDI-A3-S3 LIMOUSINE 2.0 TFSI QUATTRO"
  },
  {
    "MERK_ID": "2",
    "MERK_NAME": "BAJAJ",
    "TYPE_NAME": "AVENGER",
    "MODEL_NAME": "CRUISE 220",
    "MODEL_DESC": "BAJAJ-AVENGER-CRUISE 220"
  },
  {
    "MERK_ID": "2",
    "MERK_NAME": "BAJAJ",
    "TYPE_NAME": "AVENGER",
    "MODEL_NAME": "STREET 160",
    "MODEL_DESC": "BAJAJ-AVENGER-STREET 160"
  },
  {
    "MERK_ID": "2",
    "MERK_NAME": "BAJAJ",
    "TYPE_NAME": "CT",
    "MODEL_NAME": "100",
    "MODEL_DESC": "BAJAJ-CT-100"
  },
  {
    "MERK_ID": "3",
    "MERK_NAME": "BENELLI",
    "TYPE_NAME": "502C",
    "MODEL_NAME": "500 CC",
    "MODEL_DESC": "BENELLI-502C-500 CC"
  },
  {
    "MERK_ID": "3",
    "MERK_NAME": "BENELLI",
    "TYPE_NAME": "CAFERACER",
    "MODEL_NAME": "1130 CC",
    "MODEL_DESC": "BENELLI-CAFERACER-1130 CC"
  },
  {
    "MERK_ID": "3",
    "MERK_NAME": "BENELLI",
    "TYPE_NAME": "LEONCINO",
    "MODEL_NAME": "250",
    "MODEL_DESC": "BENELLI-LEONCINO-250"
  }
];
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <label for="autocomplete">Select Something </label>
  <input id="autocomplete">


</body>

</html>
```